# Reading Spark DataFrame from Redshift returns empty DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift, databricks

I'm using:

- python 3.6.8
- spark 2.4.4

I run `pyspark` with an EMR cluster (emr-5.28.0) with: `pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4`

I have the following jars in the spark classpath:

- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-redshift_2.11/2.0.1/spark-redshift_2.11-2.0.1.jar
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-avro_2.11/4.0.0/spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar
- https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json/releases/download/0.9.5/minimal-json-0.9.5.jar
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.15.1025/RedshiftJDBC41-no-awssdk-1.2.15.1025.jar

I execute this piece of code:

```
url = "jdbc:redshift://my.cluster:5439/my_db?user=my_user&password=my_password"
query = "select * from schema.table where trunc(timestamp)='2019-09-10'"
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.redshift')\
.option("url", url)\
.option("tempdir", "s3a://bucket/tmp_folder")\
.option("query", query)\
.option("aws_iam_role", "arn_iam_role")\
.load()
```

And doing `df.count()` it returns 73 (which is the number of rows of that query) but if I do `df.show(4)` it returns an empty DataFrame, no error, it just prints the schema.

Comment: Did you try df.show(4,false) or just df.show(). Do you see similar behavior?

Comment: Do you do the `count` and the `show` in the same cell? Are you rebinding the `df` prior to `show`? Have you considered `df.take(1)` to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work by changing the format to 'jdbc' and only use the databricks driver to write data, not read.